# Send a view to back in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-view, android-relativelayout, android-viewgroup

I am having so many views to in a relative layout which is able to *zoom* and *rotate*. what I am trying to achieve is, when I  *long click* a view it  should able to send that particular view to **last** . 
what I do is

```
   private void moveToBack(View currentView) {
        ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup) currentView.getParent());
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
            if (!v.equals(currentView)) {
                vg.bringChildToFront(v);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will set the another view above the selected view I need to send that particular view to last. *MIn sdk* is `17` and I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have something like bringToback() method so only we could modify the order of childviews. I tried once to achieve it using tricky way :

```
 public void sendViewToBack(View child) {

        final ViewGroup mParent = (ViewGroup)child.getParent();
        if (null != mParent) {
          mParent.removeView(child);
          mParent.addView(child, 0);
      }
   }
```